ng serve giving an error The working directory "C:\\Users\\srapolu\\gen-ai-latest\\gen-ai" is not an absolute path
After ng update @angular/cli and @angular/core to latest 17.3.7 version, i have removed node modules & package-lock.json. After npm install am trying to do ng serve Am getting below error error screenshot
package.json
{
  "name": "gen-ai",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:gen-ai": "node dist/gen-ai/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.8",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.17",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.14.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@sreyaj/ng-shimmer": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "node": "^20.13.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.8",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "esbuild-wasm": "~0.20.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "esbuild": "npm:esbuild-wasm@latest"
  }
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "gen-ai": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/gen-ai",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "3mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "4kb",
                  "maximumError": "5kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "gen-ai:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "gen-ai:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "gen-ai:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "4ac7a682-d5ab-401b-9d7c-9d8eee2cc564"
  }
}

Tried to reinstall the angular/cli and fresh node modules but didn't work

Could you please add your angular.json to the question? It seems like you have absolute paths there, which is not allowed, as it will only ever work on your machine.

Added the angular.json please check
